# How can I add function calls to my plugin's options.php default submit routine?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm combining two of my plugins into one. I'd like to make the activation routine of the second plugin a checkbox selection in the settings panel of the new plugin.

However, I'm unsure how to execute functions when the options are submitted. How can I do this?

The my-plugin-options.php is basically this...

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
<?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>
//options form goes here
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
<input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="check1, check2, check3, etc" />
<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
</p>
</form>
```

And its called from my main plugin file with this...

```
function my_settings_admin() {
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/my-plugin-options.php';
}

 add_options_page( 'My Plugin Settings', 
    'My Plugin Settings', 
    'manage_options', 
    'my-plugin-options.php', 
    'my_settings_admin', 
    $my_plugin_dir.'/favicon.png', 
    'top');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), then I'd say to add a check and function call for it in your sanitization callback (from register_setting).

Comment: I'm partially using it now. Checking out the tutorials at your link now. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to figure it out, between your link and this one > http://planetozh.com/blog/2009/05/handling-plugins-options-in-wordpress-28-with-register_setting/